# sympy set expectation and variance of random variable

Tags: python, probability, sympy

I have a symbol, x, in my sympy code and have been computing a number of expressions with it. Ultimately the expression I have is very long and I am only interested in its expectation under the assumption E(x) = 0, E(x^2) = 1. Is there some way to set the expectation and variance of x in advance and then ask sympy to compute expectation of my entire expression?

Answer (score 0):

Let x=stats.Bernoulli('x', 1/2, succ=1, fail=-1). Then the E and variance are what I want. So if I compute any expression with only the first two moments and take E and variance, I get the answer I want.